# In Ionic Framework using angular.js product sorting is not working fine

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Thanks in advanced.

I am facing problem in angular.

I working on a e-commerce application. Now i implement product sorting using product price only.

my html code is

```
ng-repeat="x in pc.prodListing | orderBy:pc.selectPrice | filter:pc.searchproducts"
```

i use here orderBy for sorting high to low or low to high price

i pass +

filter is working fine in my code... but result is not properly.
actually, filtering working only on first charecter
e.g if i have a array of number `(10, 100, 31, 12, 19)`
then after applying filter it return array`(10, 100, 12, 19, 31)` 
i don't know where i am wrong in my code.. and what is the main problem..

Comment: Try `selectPrice` instead of `pc.selectPrice` in `orderBy`

Comment: filter is working fine in my code... but result is not properly.
actually, filtering working only on first charecter
e.g if i have a array of number (10, 100, 31, 12, 19)
then after applying filter it return array(10, 100, 12, 19, 31) 
i don't know where i am wrong in my code.. and what is the main problem..

Comment: can you show pc.prodListing content?? I am not facing any issue. It's sorting propery from me in array (10 12 19 31 100)...may be you are using number as strings

Comment: Thanks i find solutions.
My code is not working because of the coming array is in string so that it gives error.

i change coming price list to interger value then its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i find solutions.
My code is not working because of the coming array is in string so that it gives error.

i change coming price list to interger value then its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`orderBy` is doing unicode sorting instead of number sorting. It means `selectPrice` is most likely a `string` value. Change it to a `number` using `parseInt(str)` on the backend and it will work as expected.